# Best way to send parameters to php controller with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to sent 2 parameters from the client ( jquery ) side to server side ( php-codeigniter ). The parameters are id ( an integer ) and text ( a string ). I tried:

```
window.location.href="AjaxUpdate/sendMessage/"+id+"/"+text;
```

which has worked for me in the past using only the id, but because the text string can have spaces I can get:

```
http://localhost/b1/mycontroller/myfunction/3/gdfgdgd%20&nbsp;%20&nbsp;gd
```

which gives:

```
An Error Was Encountered
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

What is the best way to prepare and transmit a string to the server side using jquery? I assume ajax will be used in some way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `.ajax()` function to POST data (`JSON`) to your PHP script, like this:

```
var postData = {
    "param1" : some_value1,
    "param2" : some_value2
};

console.log(postData);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: postData, 
    success: function(){
        alert(param1 + ' ' + param2);
        window.open("test.php"); 
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

PHP sample that I Googled and found; it doesn't seem to do much, but unfortunately I am not versed in PHP at all:

```
//request parameters
$param_1 = $_POST['param1'];
$param_2 = $_POST['param2'];

echo 'postData: ' . var_dump($_POST);

if ($_POST)){
    echo $param_1;
    echo $param_2;
} else {
    echo 'problem';
}
```

Comment: Can you also clarify how to relieve this in php?

Comment: I am not a PHP person, but I have updated my answer with a snippet of PHP code that might do what you are looking for. See updated section. Is it common for PHP to simply `echo` back values, I have seen lots of PHP snippets that do this or is this the easy way of having the server return something to the client?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. On my system even though I can see the parameters in the request in firebug , and ajax success actions are being performed, the $_POST array is empty on the server side. I'll take this up tomorrow. Regards - Bill